# Laravel Eloquent - Do not run relationship query if column value is NULL or 0

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have various relationships within my `Eloquent` `Models` that look like this:

```
public function main_image()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Media::class, 'id', 'main_image_id');
}
```

However, it will run a SQL query if the `main_image_id` is null or 0, so I end up with a number of queries like this:

```
select * from `media` where `media`.`id` is null and `media`.`id` is not null limit 1
```

Which obviously will not return anything, but still wastes resources. Is there any way of automatically checking for that?

Currently what I do is have a method, like `hasMainImage()`, that checks that `main_image_id` is not null and not 0, but a lot of the current system already uses the relationships, and I was wondering if I can add the check to the relationship method itself?

I have tried adding a check to it and return `null` if the column has no real value, but I've got an `Exception` that it has to return a Relation object. Or if I'm trying to Eager load it, I receive following error:

`Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null`

```
public function main_image()
{
    if (!$this->main_image_id) {
        return null;
    }

    return $this->hasOne('App\Modules\Media\Models\Media', 'id', 'main_image_id');
}
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
A perhaps more clear example:

```
$page = Page::find(1);
var_dump($page->main_image); // This will run a query as shown above that is guaranteed to return nothing
// Since at this point system knows that $page->main_image_id is 0 or null, I would like to use that to not run the query and automatically set $page->main_image to null
```

Comment: Doing a `with` uses additional resources. You should not do it in the first place, not do it everywhere and then try to hack around it.

Comment: `with` is not used everywhere, only where multiple models are loaded at once. When only single instance is loaded, `with` is not used, and calls like  `$page->main_image` are made. Those are the calls I'm trying to optimise here

Comment: There's no additional benefit if you're doing that. The join will happen either way, it will just return less things. I am of course assuming you have a one-to-one relationship here.

Comment: My goal is not to run a SQL query, when I am doing a call like `$page->main_image` when I know that `$page->main_image_id` is `0` or `null`. And I need that check at the Model's method level.

Comment: If you eager load, then the `$page->main_image` does not/should not trigger a single query. The query is done pre-emptively on the entire result set.

Comment: I do not eager load. As I mentioned, that is the case I want to avoid running useless SQL queries - when I load just a single instance (so one `Page` for example) and then my views call stuff like `$page->main_image`, because the program knows that `main_image_id` I am trying to find the best way to put that as a condition and just return null before even running the SQL query.

Comment: `addEagerConstraints` wouldn't have been called if you weren't eager loading. Perhaps you meant to do something like `$page->main_image_id!=null?$page->main_image()->get():null`?

Comment: Yes, that was an example of Exception that I don't want to receive when I eager load. When I eager load, I understand that the query will be run either way, I just want to address the issue when I am not eager loading. Yes, the snippet you provided would work, but main issue is that `page->main_image` is already called in the system from many views (so it's a lengthy refactor), so I wondering if that same check could be done at the method-level.

Comment: That's the "hacking around" it point I was trying to make to begin with. I doubt it can be done, and would not recommend it either as that might cause other framework features to not work for that model as well.

Comment: Yes, the checks are being done now, however, they were not in a big part of a system. My current best idea is to have a `__construct` method that does such check and sets the attribute to null, so the relation method is never even called if the column value is 0 or null on an instance.

Answer (score 0):

You declare your relations in wrong order, [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) is clear about this.

The entity that does no make sense by itself (without its "parent" you may say) should incorporate "belongsTo" relation (as documentation says inverse).

For demonstration lets say you have User model and you have many details about that user so you create Detail model.

Now User model should have detail relation:

```
public function detail() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Detail', 'user_id', 'id'); //you can see the difference here from your code sample, you have 2nd and 3rd parameter reversed
}
```

And Detail model should have user relation:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Comment: That is not the structure that I currently have. I have `Page` model, and `Media` model. `Media` model is a self-containing model not attached to any others (as it can be used many times by different models and model instances). `Page` has a `main_image` method (as defined in quetstion) that defines the relationship to the `Media`. I do not want to run a SQL query if I know beforehand that it will not return anything. I am not sure how defining `belongsTo` in the `Media` Model addresses this issue? I do not need to access any other Models from within the `Media` instance either way.

Comment: Not in this case. `Page` Model can have a single `Media` related to it as a `main_image`, however, the same `Media` model can be related to other pages as `main_image`, and a number of other Models as different kinds of images. So `Page` "has one" Media object, which is referenced in the `pages` table as `main_image_id`. I am wondering if I should be using `belongsTo` relation here? And whether that would make any difference in running the queries? I assume it will run the SQL queries I want to get rid of either way as there might be a 0 in there.

Comment: I understand what you mean about the wrong order now. However, I have switched `hasOne` to `belongsTo` and it made no difference in the queries and the issue I am trying to solve here.

Comment: @Giedrius Demonstrate how you access the entity in question.

Comment: I still stand behind my first point that I made in answer, you have reversed the order of relationship. In my example with user and its detail, user entity does not hold any information about "detail" therefore when I simply do `App\User::find(15)` it gets me object User without detail and one query is run. In another hand I want detail of user (with id 15) and that detail does not exist it runs 2 queries `App\User::find(15)->detail` which is correct.

Comment: My relationship is reversed - the `Media` model does not hold any information about the Page. So I can retrieve Page as such `Page::find(1)` and then if I want to get its main image Media, I can go `$page->main_image`. But at that point system already knows that `$page->main_image_id` is null or 0, and should not run a query that guaranteed will return nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147375/discussion-between-kyslik-and-giedrius).

Comment: @Giedrius hey, good news https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19733 monitor that PR and if its merged you can use `->withDefault()` and set "empty" relation, not sure if its going to hit the table yet but its something that would help your case.