# Laravel Eloquent - Override Model's constructor to change attributes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have a `Page` Model, which extends the `Eloquent` `Model` class. I am trying to override the constructor, where I need some additional logic. This is what I currently have:

```
class Page extends Model
{

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {

        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->main_image = null;
    }

}
```

But this does not seem to save the `main_image` into the `$this->attributes` property when I call `Page::find(1);`.

I believe this is because `Page::find` eventually calls `Model::newFromBuilder`, which looks like this:

```
public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null)
{
    $model = $this->newInstance([], true);

    $model->setRawAttributes((array) $attributes, true);

    $model->setConnection($connection ?: $this->getConnectionName());

    return $model;
}
```

So as you can see it creates the instance first and then sets the attributes, which means that anything set in the constructor gets ignored.

Is there any workaround for this to be able to override constructor (or similar method) to change the attributes for every retrieved/created model instance? Obviously I could override the `newFromBuilder`, `newInstance`, `__construct` and similar methods, but this seems very hacky and unmaintainable.

Thanks!

Comment: So basically you want to override one parameter whenever you create a new element? You should use model events for that, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events - especially look at "creating/created".

Comment: The overriding was just an example, there may be multiple parameters overriding and they would be wrapped in if statements etc. I will check out the events, if I can apply them to all classes without writing an Observer class for each Model I've got. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason your model doesn't already have the `main_image` field? What's the end goal of setting it inside the model? There might be another approach to the problem potentially with more information, potentially if all pages have a `main_image` a relationship could be formed so that you can do `$page->mainImage->get()`

Comment: The reason behind this is a potential solution to another problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699673/laravel-eloquent-do-not-run-relationship-query-if-column-value-is-null-or-0
So I want to check if `$page->main_image_id` is empty, to set `$page->main_image` to null and do not call the relation method

Answer (score 6):

If all you need is to be able automatically modify a model's attribute when retrieved or set, then use [Laravel Eloquent's Accesors and Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators):

**Defining An Accessor**

To define an accessor, create a getFooAttribute method on your model where Foo is the "studly" cased name of the column you wish to access. In this example, we'll define an accessor for the  first_name attribute. The accessor will automatically be called by Eloquent when attempting to retrieve the value of the first_name attribute:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the original value of the column is passed to the accessor, allowing you to manipulate and return the value. To access the value of the accessor, you may simply access the  first_name attribute on a model instance:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$firstName = $user->first_name;
```

**Defining A Mutator**

To define a mutator, define a setFooAttribute method on your model where Foo is the "studly" cased name of the column you wish to access. So, again, let's define a mutator for the first_name attribute. This mutator will be automatically called when we attempt to set the value of the  first_name attribute on the model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Set the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['first_name'] = strtolower($value);
    }
}
```

The mutator will receive the value that is being set on the attribute, allowing you to manipulate the value and set the manipulated value on the Eloquent model's internal $attributes property. So, for example, if we attempt to set the first_name attribute to Sally:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$user->first_name = 'Sally';
```

In this example, the setFirstNameAttribute function will be called with the value Sally. The mutator will then apply the strtolower function to the name and set its resulting value in the internal $attributes array.